# Grouping Gaps between Dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find a function that would allow me to create to turn raw dates into episodes where I set the parameter of what constitutes an episode. for this example 3 days gap between dates would be a new "episode" but would eventually like to scale it to be any x =

I have tried the gap and island problem as well as lead and lag 1 day period, but cant get the code to give me a row for each window interval of 3 days.

```
drop table RUNNING_LOG;
create table running_log ( 
    run_date          date not null,  
    time_in_seconds   int  not null, 
    distance_in_miles int  not null
);
truncate table running_log;

begin  
    insert into running_log values (date'2018-01-01', 420, 1);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2018-01-02', 2400, 5);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2018-01-03', 2430, 5);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2018-02-06', 2350, 5);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2018-02-07', 410, 1);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2018-07-10', 400, 1); ---4 month gap 
    insert into running_log values (date'2018-08-13', 2300, 5);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2018-12-31', 425, 1);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2019-01-01', 422, 1);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2019-01-06', 2350, 5);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2019-02-07', 410, 1);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2019-06-10', 400, 1);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2019-07-13', 2300, 5);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2019-08-14', 425, 1);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2019-12-15', 422, 1);
    insert into running_log values (date'2020-01-01', 425, 1);  
    insert into running_log values (date'2020-03-31', 422, 1); 
    insert into running_log values (date'2020-04-15', 422, 1);
    insert into running_log values (date'2020-06-01', 425, 1); 
    insert into running_log values (date'2020-07-06', 425, 1); 
    insert into running_log values (date'2021-03-31', 422, 1);  
    commit;  
end;

select * from running_log
```

Ideally I would like to build a table that has aggregated data both the begin_date for days 3 or greater and aggregated row for less than 3 days. The below code only does 1 day gaps and doesnt provider begin_date end_date for each interval.

```
with grps as (  
  select run_date
        , row_number() over (order by run_date) rn ,  
         run_date - row_number() over (order by run_date) grp_date  
  from   running_log  
)  
  select min(run_date) first_run
        , max(run_date) last_run,   
         count(*) runs,   
         row_number() over (order by min(run_date)) grp  
  from   grps  
  group  by grp_date  
  order  by min(run_date)
```

Again a row would be 1. Gap of 3 days or aggregation of days between the 3.

Comment: Thanks Tinkinc.  What database version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

That's indeed some kind of gaps and island problem.

You would need several levels of subquerying to handle this. First compute the `ROW_NUMBER()` and use `LAG()` to get the previous `run_date` value, then do a conditional sum depending on the gaps between the consecutive records. Finally, the difference between the row number and the conditional sum gives you the groups.

Consider:

```
SELECT
    MIN(run_date) first_run,
    MAX(run_date) last_run,
    COUNT(*) runs
FROM (
    SELECT 
        x.*,
        SUM(CASE WHEN run_date - lg <= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY run_date) rn2
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            t.*, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY run_date) rn1,
            LAG(run_date) OVER(ORDER BY run_date) lg,
        FROM running_log t
    ) x
) y
GROUP BY rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY 1
```

To adapt the length of the allowed gap, you can change simply modify the expression in the conditional sum: `run_date - lg <= :max_gap_length`

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=55d5d9f9e6be43ae3d289c7ad3651057)** with your sample data returns:

```
FIRST_RUN | LAST_RUN  | RUNS
:-------- | :-------- | ---:
01-JAN-18 | 03-JAN-18 |    3
06-FEB-18 | 07-FEB-18 |    2
10-JUL-18 | 10-JUL-18 |    1
13-AUG-18 | 13-AUG-18 |    1
31-DEC-18 | 01-JAN-19 |    2
06-JAN-19 | 06-JAN-19 |    1
07-FEB-19 | 07-FEB-19 |    1
10-JUN-19 | 10-JUN-19 |    1
13-JUL-19 | 13-JUL-19 |    1
14-AUG-19 | 14-AUG-19 |    1
15-DEC-19 | 15-DEC-19 |    1
01-JAN-20 | 01-JAN-20 |    1
31-MAR-20 | 31-MAR-20 |    1
15-APR-20 | 15-APR-20 |    1
01-JUN-20 | 01-JUN-20 |    1
06-JUL-20 | 06-JUL-20 |    1
31-MAR-21 | 31-MAR-21 |    1
```

NB: *that* was an interesting question!

Comment: I need to roll up everything into a min and max especially when it's less than 3 or x days different

Comment: @Tinkinc: that's exactly what the query intends to do... Do you see something wrong in the results of the query when I run it in the db fiddle against your sample data?

Comment: yes it doesn't create episodes in consecutive order based on gaps. lets say there are 75 runs recorded and we wanted to see when someone stopped running for >40 days gap between Date x and date y. that would be a break and a new episode until the same thing happened again at an interval greater than 40.All days that are less than 40 are bundled as well into a single episode.

Comment: @Tinkinc: once again, that's what the query does. As it is, it breaks into a new episode (ie a new record) as soon as it detects a gaps greater than 3 days between 2 consecutive runs. You can adapt the size of the gap as needed, by changing expression `run_date - lg <= 3` to whatever fits your need.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for this kind of query.
Its raison d'être is to detect patterns across multiple rows.

For your provided data-set and using 3 days as the gap between groups, an example would be:

```
SELECT EPISODE_NUMBER, FIRST_RUN, LAST_RUN, RUNS_IN_EPISODE
FROM RUNNING_LOG
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
        ORDER BY RUN_DATE
        MEASURES
            MATCH_NUMBER() AS EPISODE_NUMBER,
            MIN(RUN_DATE) AS FIRST_RUN,
            MAX(RUN_DATE) AS LAST_RUN,
            COUNT(*) AS RUNS_IN_EPISODE
        PATTERN (EPISODE_START IN_EPISODE*)
        DEFINE IN_EPISODE AS RUN_DATE <= PREV(RUN_DATE + 3));
```

Result:

```
   EPISODE_NUMBER    FIRST_RUN     LAST_RUN    RUNS_IN_EPISODE
_________________ ____________ ____________ __________________
                1 01-JAN-18    03-JAN-18                     3
                2 06-FEB-18    07-FEB-18                     2
                3 10-JUL-18    10-JUL-18                     1
                4 13-AUG-18    13-AUG-18                     1
                5 31-DEC-18    01-JAN-19                     2
                6 06-JAN-19    06-JAN-19                     1
                7 07-FEB-19    07-FEB-19                     1
                8 10-JUN-19    10-JUN-19                     1
                9 13-JUL-19    13-JUL-19                     1
               10 14-AUG-19    14-AUG-19                     1
               11 15-DEC-19    15-DEC-19                     1
               12 01-JAN-20    01-JAN-20                     1
               13 31-MAR-20    31-MAR-20                     1
               14 15-APR-20    15-APR-20                     1
               15 01-JUN-20    01-JUN-20                     1
               16 06-JUL-20    06-JUL-20                     1
               17 31-MAR-21    31-MAR-21                     1

17 rows selected.
```

`MATCH_RECOGNIZE` has this anatomy:

`ORDER BY` just defines the order in which to process the rows
`MEASURES` are analytics against each partition
`PATTERN` is where the episodes are defined.  Here it is any run to `EPISODE_START`, then zero or more runs `IN_EPISODE`
`DEFINE` is the criteria used by the pattern.  Here it is how many days between runs to qualify as `IN_EPISODE`

The **[+ 3]** in the above could be adjusted up or down to make for more or less inclusive groups.

Using **[+ 100]** instead, makes fewer episodes, with more runs in each

Result:

```
   EPISODE_NUMBER    FIRST_RUN     LAST_RUN    RUNS_IN_EPISODE
_________________ ____________ ____________ __________________
                1 01-JAN-18    07-FEB-18                     5
                2 10-JUL-18    13-AUG-18                     2
                3 31-DEC-18    07-FEB-19                     4
                4 10-JUN-19    14-AUG-19                     3
                5 15-DEC-19    06-JUL-20                     6
                6 31-MAR-21    31-MAR-21                     1

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: Sadly I'm on 11g. Sigh

Comment: @Tinkinc ouch.  That's too bad.  It won't help on this, but maybe worth a talk with your DBA's sometime.  The migration right to 18/19c might hurt, but going to 12.1 is pretty clean.